# Is there a way to Add new Route into React native Stack navigation dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

We are building an app in which are using React native stack Navigation, 
Depends in the web api call based on the output we want to add the redirect to the same type of screen with different data and that new screen can create another screen..

We are using stack navigation with a single route at the start of the app. 
Based on the Web Api call i want to inject a new Route to the existing stack and it should be able to go back to the previous screens

Is there Any way to achieve this.?

Comment: Unfortunately not, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/limitations.html#dynamic-routes

Comment: Can you discuss the scenario in which you need to do this ? Usually the params passed onto nav are dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

> If we call this.props.navigation.navigate with a route name that we haven't defined on a stack navigator, nothing will happen. Said another way, we can only navigate to routes that have been defined on our stack navigator — we cannot navigate to an arbitrary component.

Comment: is it possible to insert a route into my current stack and then redirect to that .?

Comment: As stated, only if you've defined the route earlier in your stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create all possible routes for app and according to web api just navigate app the what screen do you want with any data. It's all up to you.

Comment: no it will be a dynamic pages. We will be opening the same screen multiple times one after the other each with different state(data).

Comment: so we want to push the same screen with diff route name dynamically

Comment: Route name is just a name that you know. You can customize the title that displaying on screen header. So you can for example give a name "AddAndEditPage' and when you route for add you can set title "ADD" or when you rout for edit you can set title for "EDIT"

Answer (score 0):

According to React Navigation Documents, you can change your stack whenever you want:

`index` is the index of the route you want to navigate on new `actions` array of routes. (in this case we want to navigate to route `'NewRoute'` and its `index` is `1`)

```
import {StackActions, NavigationActions} from "react-navigation"

class Example extends Component {

  // ... Some other methods

  navigate = (id) => {
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 1,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'NewRoute', params: { id, ...otherParams } }),
      ],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.navigate()}>
          <Text>Go to New Route</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i couldn't get the answer. Will it allow to push the new stack .?